# Entity Framework Core - Upsert entities from other database encounters tracking problems

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a flatfile from a different database. I import it and map it to my application's entities. Because the flatfile does not contain ids I cannot be sure the entries I handle are not duplicates of what has already been added to my database earlier or to my context at this moment.
The error message I get is:

> The instance of entity type 'Car' cannot be tracked because another
>   instance with the same key value for {'Make', 'Model'} is already
>   being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.

An example:

Data rows from flatfile

```
Volvo V70 Steve
Volvo V70 John
```

Having mapped these rows and trying to put them in db

```cs
foreach(var row in flatFileRows){
   Car existingCar = null;

   if(dbContext.Cars.Any(c => c.Make == row.Make && c.Model == row.Model)){
      existingCar = dbContext.Cars
     .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Make == row.Make && c.Model == row.Model);
   }
   //I also do the same for existingDriver

   var car = existingCar != null
    ? existingCar
    : new Car()
    {
        Make = row.Make,
        Model = row.Model,
        Drivers = new List<Driver>();
    };

    var driver = new Driver()
    {
        CarId = existingCar != null ? exsitingCar.Id : 0,
        Name = row.Name
    };

   car.Drivers.Add(driver);

   dbContext.Cars.Update(car); //Second time we hit this the error is thrown
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Make and Model are set to keys in the schema because I don't want duplicate entries of the car models.

The above example is simplified.

What I want is to check if I already put a car in the db with these attributes and then build according to my schema from that entity. I don't care to track any entries, disconnected or otherwise, because I just need to populate the database.

Comment: why do you call Update(car) anyways, when it hasn't been changed?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, in the scenario of reading from the flatfile I don't know what parameters has been changed, nor which objects in the tree with its root in Car. So I update Car with the attached objects as an upsert.